# How to end the process?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

In this part

```
if (File.Exists(filePath)) {
      string status = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(filePath)).ReadLine();

      if (status != "SUCCEEDED") {
           File.Delete(filePath);
           createDb();
      } 
}
```

the program gives an exception with the message

> The process can not access the file '\STATUS.txt' because it is being
>   used by another process.

how to fix this?

Comment: You need to close your stream.

Comment: thanks, it did the work

Answer (score 4):

Modify your code to something like this:

```
if (File.Exists(filePath)) 
{
    string status;
    using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        status = streamReader.ReadLine();
    }

    if (status != "SUCCEEDED")
    {
        File.Delete(filePath);
        createDb();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `using` pattern:

```
if (File.Exists(filePath)) {
    using(var stream = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(filePath)))
    {
      var status = stream.ReadLine();
      if (status != "SUCCEEDED")
      {
        File.Delete(filePath);
        createDb();
      } 
    }
 }
```

Then if somene else is using the file, you can open the stream as below:

```
 new FileStream(fi.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Delete | FileShare.ReadWrite))
```

ant then pass to the StreamReader constructor.

Comment: You actually don't need to use `File.OpenRead`. You can use this ctor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/f2ke0fzy

Comment: @thefiloe correct, just reused the OP code as is, but useful for the rest of the answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

you should close the stream before you delete the file
try this one

```
if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            string status= string.Empty;
            using (var stream = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(filePath)))
            {
                status = stream.ReadLine();
            }
            if (status != "SUCCEEDED")
            {
                File.Delete(filePath);
                createDb();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the file before deleting it or write it in using block.

```
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    string status= string.Empty;
    using (var stream = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(filePath)))
    {
        status = stream.ReadLine();
    }
    if (status != "SUCCEEDED")
    {
        File.Delete(filePath);
        createDb();
    }
}
```

Comment: `status` is a string. You can't close a string.

Comment: @thefiloe: My bad. I was in such a hurry while answering. Corrected the answer. Thanks.